# Classification vs Regression Algorithms - Should exists algorithms only for Classification and/or Regression

Tags: classification, regression, algorithms

Dummy question:

There exists algorithms that should only be used for Classification or Regression problems?

For example, should Random Forest should only be apply on Classification problems and Neural Networks for Regression problems?

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can think of a regression as being a classification with a very large number of ordinal classes, therefore algorithms can be used for both. 
Indeed you can build a regression with a random forest, and a neural network can be used both as a regressor or a classifier depending on the activation function of its output layer.